# Some confirmation on hashmaps and terminology C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, hashmap

I'm doing a lab for my introduction to C++ and we've started on a username and password database where my professor wants us to implement as hashmap with a dynamically allocated array of LinkedLists. I just want some confirmation on what I'm doing so that I know I'm doing it correctly...

1) Buckets is where information will be stored. I presume each bucket is a singly LinkedList.

2) A hash function % number of buckets will determine which index I use in my array to store the user and password information.

3) Key-Value ... I'm a little confused by this. Is the key my username, and the value my password?

4) Load Factor is the number of keys stored divided by the number of buckets. So in my case, if I had 50 users stored in my hashmap, would it be 50/100? My head has a hard time wrapping around this concept. Does this mean not every bucket will be used sometimes?

Comment: And your professor refuses to answer those questions and hasn't given you any introduction into the concept of hashmaps?

Comment: He's quite vague on them. If you don't wish to answer the questions feel free to continue on your way. And no he hasn't.

Comment: He's given a theoretical explanation but nothing too immersive.

Comment: What do you mean by "bucket" this is not a c++ term. A linked list is std::list, an array (probably) std::array and a hashmap std::map. May reading about these days structures answers done of your questions. And yes, you teacher should and those questions, but this is not your fault.

Comment: I feel totally free to continue exactly my way. And that means, that I'd like point out that you haven't even posted a single line of own code.

Comment: I asked a question about how a specific content in C++ worked. It doesn't make sense to provide code. You're just being unfriendly.

Comment: Better mind your own manners This "If you don't wish to answer the questions feel free to continue on your way" was by no means an appropriate answer of the question I asked you for clarification's sake.

Comment: You gave attitude in your response. I merely responded the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Correct. Ideally each "bucket" would only hold one value. If there are conflicts in the hash algorithm then multiple values would be stored in the same bucket, hence the use of a linked list.

2) Correct. The hash algorithm is what allows you to know where to store/retrieve data in the hashmap.

3) Correct.

4) Correct. You do not want the load factor of the hashmap to be too high, otherwise the running time for inserting/retrieving begins to approach O(N). The useful aspect of hashing is that it (ideally) allows for insertion and retrieval in O(1) time when the load factor is low.

Typically once the load factor reaches a certain level, the size of the hashmap is increased and rehashed in order to lower the load factor. A hashmap uses more space than a typical array would, but this is generally offset by the speed of inserting/retrieving data from it.

Comment: Addendum to 2: The fun part is computing the hash value in such a way that you maximize uniqueness (thus minimizing collisions--multiple values in the same bucket) without making the computation so intensive that it overshadows the low cost of retrieving the stored items.

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes. Each bucket would hold a linked list. Singly linked is common.

2) Yep, sounds typical.

3) Yes.

4) Yep. If you have 100 buckets and 50 entries, than you have an average linked list length of 0.5. By necessity that would mean at least half will have no entries.